# Why does my iterative implementation of drop for a linked list still cause a stack overflow?

Tags: list, rust, stack-overflow

I am following [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/first-final.html) to write my first program in Rust. I **changed** the program to:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum List {
    Nil,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    val: i32,
    next: List
}

impl List {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List::Nil
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, v : i32) {
        let old_head = mem::replace(&mut *self, List::Nil);
        let new_head = List::More(Box::new(Node { val : v, next: old_head}));
        *self = new_head
    }

    pub fn remove(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        match mem::replace(&mut *self, List::Nil) {
            List::Nil => {
                None
            },
            List::More(ref mut boxed_node) => {
                let result = Some(boxed_node.val);
                *self = mem::replace(&mut boxed_node.next, List::Nil);
                result
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut head = mem::replace(&mut *self, List::Nil);

        while let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) {
            head = mem::replace(&mut node.next, List::Nil);
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::List;

    #[test]
    fn basics() {
        let mut list = List::new();
        list.insert(7);
        assert_eq!(Some(7), list.remove());
        assert_eq!(None, list.remove());

        list.insert(1);
        list.insert(2);
        list.insert(3);

        assert_eq!(Some(3), list.remove());
        assert_eq!(Some(2), list.remove());
        assert_eq!(Some(1), list.remove());
        assert_eq!(None, list.remove());
    }

    #[test]
    fn drop_long_list() {
        let mut list = List::new();
        for i in 1..100000 {
            list.insert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Both of my tests are failing with a stack overflow in `drop`. Is it because of `*self` in RHS?

I don't know what is happening with `let mut head = mem::replace(&mut *self, List::Nil);`.

My understanding is:

1. It sets `List::Nil` in `self`.
2. Puts original value of `self` in `head`.

Is `*self` doing something more?

I also tried this version of `drop`:

```
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);

        while let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) {
            head = mem::replace(&mut node.next, List::Nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Another try:

```
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        while true {
            match self {
                &mut List::Nil => break,
                &mut List::More(ref mut node) => {
                    *self = mem::replace(&mut node.next, List::Nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*self` because it is borrowed
  --> src\list.rs:48:21
   |
47 |                 &mut List::More(ref mut node) => {
   |                                 ------------ borrow of `*self` occurs here
48 |                     *self = mem::replace(&mut node.next, List::Nil)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `*self` occurs here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you write recursive (or iterative) code, **you need to have a stopping condition**. Your code doesn't, so it loops forever.

---

Producing a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem is always a good start:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum List {
    Nil,
    More(Box<List>),
}

impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);

        while let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) {
            head = mem::replace(node, List::Nil);
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn basics() {
    List::Nil;
}
```

Then annotate the code to see where it's recurring:

```
fn drop(&mut self) {
    eprintln!("1");
    let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);
    eprintln!("2");
    while let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) {
        eprintln!("3");
        head = mem::replace(node, List::Nil);
        eprintln!("4");
    }
    eprintln!("5");
}
```

This prints out

```
1
2
1
2
```

so delete everything after that:

```
fn drop(&mut self) {
    eprintln!("1");
    let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);
    eprintln!("2");
}
```

Why does this cause infinite recursion? You've defined it so that in order to drop `List`, you have to create a new `List`, which in turn needs to be dropped, which creates a new `List`, which...

Add a stopping condition:

```
fn drop(&mut self) {
    if let List::Nil = *self { return }

    let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);

    while let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) {
        head = mem::replace(node, List::Nil);
    }
}
```

No more infinite recursion.

Then expand back out to the original and try again. It works for this test case, but not for `List::More(Box::new(List::Nil))` so we shrink it back:

```
fn drop(&mut self) {
    eprintln!("1");
    if let List::Nil = *self { return }
    eprintln!("2");
    let mut head = mem::replace(&mut *self, List::Nil);
    eprintln!("3");
    while let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) {
        eprintln!("4");
        head = mem::replace(node, List::Nil);
        eprintln!("5");
    }
    eprintln!("6");
}
```

```
1
2
3
4
1
5
1
2
3
4
1
5
```

The problem now is that when we re-assign `head`, the value we are overwriting needs to be dropped, which triggers the recursion again.

Fixing this is *complicated*. Like, surprisingly so. You ready for this?

```
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match *self {
            List::Nil => return,
            List::More(ref more) => {
                if let List::Nil = **more {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);

        while let List::More(ref mut next) = {head} {
            head = mem::replace(next, List::Nil);
        }
    }
}
```

This now has **two** stopping conditions:

1. `Nil`
2. `More(Nil)`

In every other case, we iteratively convert the `More(x)` into a `More(Nil)`, which is handled by the stopping condition. That means that we only have a single depth of recursion: *for each value* that is dropped when the previous value of `head` goes out of scope when it is replaced.

---

For your original code:

```
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match *self {
            List::Nil => return,
            List::More(ref more) => {
                if let List::Nil = more.next {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);

        while let List::More(ref mut node) = {head} {
            head = mem::replace(&mut node.next, List::Nil);
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the original tutorial you linked, this isn't a problem because the definition of `List::drop` doesn't modify `self` at all so it's not self-recursive:

```
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let mut cur_link = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty);
        while let Link::More(mut boxed_node) = cur_link {
            cur_link = mem::replace(&mut boxed_node.next, Link::Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this was discussed earlier in comments of first question. Its not working: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3f3105c83137c13fef0b9829515e98ba&version=stable  Or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: i meant.. comments of *aochagavia* answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a stack overflow because your drop function is infinitely recursive.

The code below:

```
let mut head = mem::replace(self, List::Nil);
```

Stores a `List` object in `head`, which will be dropped at the end of the scope. This means that, while you are dropping, you create a new list which also needs to be dropped. Repeat this enough times and you get a stack overflow.

**Note**: in the tutorial you linked, they use `let mut cur_link = mem::replace(&mut self.head, Link::Empty)` to avoid recursion.

Comment: but isn't i am mutating head to nil with `let List::More(ref mut node) = mem::replace(&mut head, List::Nil) ` in while loop ?

Comment: Also, data structure in my code is different from that of tutorial. hence, some changes.

Comment: even if you set head to `Nil`, it will be dropped again

Comment: Can you give some documentation around this ?  i want to understand this.

Comment: I think this answer is a good start, but this can't be the only mistake, otherwise inserting `if let List::Nil = *self { return; }` at the top of `drop` would fix it, right (see https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c14762118e88c9e9230610b356a7dc65&version=stable)?

Comment: @Stefan its not he nil case that is the problem. I think problem is to write drop for this list without creating another reference to self.

Comment: @Stefan, aochagavia: It isn't just `head` that is the problem, it's also the temporary value returned by the `mem::replace` in the `while` loop condition.

Comment: @aochagavia i tried another version. but it seems that its not compiling for me. Can you suggest something ?