# Why does this Rust binary tree overflow its stack in tests?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've written a binary tree-like structure, but I've been getting stack-overflow errors in some of my stress tests. I've reduced the error-causing code down to the following:
    struct Node {
        index: usize,
        right: Option>,
    }

```
struct BoxedTree {
    root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

fn build_degenerate() {
    let mut t = BoxedTree {
        root: Some(Box::new(Node {
            index: 0,
            right: None,
        })),
    };
    let mut n = t.root.as_mut().unwrap();
    for i in 1..50000 {
        let cur = n;
        let p = &mut cur.right;
        *p = Some(Box::new(Node {
            index: i,
            right: None,
        }));
        n = p.as_mut().unwrap();
    }
    println!("{}", n.index);
}

fn main() {
    build_degenerate();
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn mytest() {
        build_degenerate();
    }
}
```

Running `cargo test` gives me:

```
running 1 test

thread 'tests::mytest' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
error: process didn't exit successfully: ...
```

I don't understand how this code could be causing a stack overflow, as all data seems to be allocated on the heap, and there is no recursion.

Even stranger, this code causes an overflow when I run `cargo test`, but not when I run `cargo run`, even though `mytest` and `main` call the same code.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Do we need to manually create a destructor for a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38147453/155423),  [Why does my iterative implementation of drop for a linked list still cause a stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47051923/155423) and [cargo test --release causes a stack overflow. Why doesn't cargo bench?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42955243/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR: "and there is no recursion" is a lie and tests have a smaller stack size.

Comment: Ah, so the default destructor is recursive; that makes perfect sense, thank you.